# Why doesn't this CSS selector work: a:hover ~ span?

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, css-selectors

```
a:hover + span { background:yellow; }
a:hover > span { background:yellow; }
a:hover ~ span { background:yellow; }
```

The first two selectors work just fine. However, the third selector does not work?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UAHw7/

Why?

---

**Update:** I fired up all my browsers ...

Opera 11 - Works
Safari 5 - Works
Firefox 3.6 - Works
IE9 RC - Works
Chrome 9 - Does not work

A Chrome issue then ...

---

### Note: As Chrome no longer contains this bug, this question is obsolete.

Comment: @tenfour When you hover the ANCHOR all three SPAN elements should light up yellow...

Comment: Weird. Interestingly, it works if you drop the `:hover` pseudo-class.

Comment: does for me... Maybe your browser doesn't support CSS3? (even made it #FF00FF just to avoid confusion, and worked flawlessly on FF4)

Comment: @Brad doesn't work in Chrome 9

Comment: @Pekka: Is CSS3 "officially released" yet? Could it just be some browsers have and haven't full implemented it?

Comment: @Brad nope, but it works when I drop `:hover` which makes me think it's a bug or at least a bug-like phenomenon :) Edit: It even works in IE8.

Comment: @Pekka: Undocumented feature. ;-) And I'm thinking it's just not implemented yet.

Comment: @Brad CSS3 Selectors are currently at "proposed recommendation" level, which means that it's pretty mature.

Comment: It works for you in Safari 5? Doesn't for me

Comment: @Pekka Yep, Safari 5.0.3 on Win7.

Comment: Weird, same for me and it doesn't work, behaves just like in Chrome.

Comment: Safari 4.0 doesn't work either.  Must be a bug.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a Webkit bug related to using the `:hover` pseudo-class.

It works fine for me

- in FF 3.6.13
- in IE 8 of all browsers
- in Opera 11

It doesn't work for me

- In Chrome 9
- In Safari 5.0.3

Might be file-worthy.

Comment: I had to laugh at "of all browsers". What, you insinuating IE's not always compliant? :grin:

Comment: Seems to be a Webkit issue. It has been mentioned here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=30753#c4

Comment: @Šime yup, that looks like it

Comment: What a bummer... `A:hover ~ B` is such a nice feature, and now I can't use it because of stupid Chrome `:)`

Comment: @Šime yeah, that's unusual! IE 8 does it, but cutting-edge Chrome does not. Doesn't happen every day. :)

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that you can't combine the general sibling selector `~` with the pseudo-class `:hover`; note that if you change the selector to `a ~ span` then both of the `span` elements turn yellow.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Chrome has a `:hover` problem. Especially for `<a>`.

1. `:hover` doesn't work in Chrome:
   `<a>Link</a>`
2. `:hover` works in Chrome:
   `<a href="#">Link</a>`
3. `:hover` works in Chrome:
   `<a href="javascript:void(0);">Link</a>`

Note: You can use `href="javascript:void(0)"` instead of `href="#"`. I prefer `javascript:void(0)`.

Comment: Works on Chrome 23 even for First 1 ie `<a>Link</a>`