# Webkit bug with `:hover` and multiple adjacent-sibling selectors

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, webkit, css-selectors

Safari and Chrome, as well as Opera and Firefox, can handle the `:hover` pseudo-class and adjacent-sibling selectors:

`a:hover + div {}`

This works.

However, when another adjacent-sibling is added:

`div:hover + a + div {}`

Webkit falls apart.

However, if you first hover over `<a>` and *then* hover over the `<div>` the style is applied as it ought to.

I'm further confounded, because if you add:

`div:hover ~ div {}`

with or without a style declared, it starts working as it ought to.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ds2yY/)

I see this problem in:

- Google Chrome 15.0.874.121
- Safari 5.1.1

for OS X.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, this is a WebKit bug. I come across it occasionally. Elements apart from the `:hover`ed one and its parents aren't updated. Nothing you can do about it, I'm afraid.

Comment: Somebody observed completely opposite behavior here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061509/why-doesnt-this-css-selector-work-ahover-span Definitely a WebKit bug either way, and one that apparently hasn't been completely fixed yet.

Comment: I found a more elegant solution to this on a [more recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219286/why-does-the-general-sibling-combinator-allow-toggling-pseudo-elements-content/17220145#17220145), so I posted a similar answer here.

Comment: Seems to apply also in to a :checked selector.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

you can overcome Webkit's pseudo classes + general/adjacent sibling selectors bugs by faking animation on the body element:

```
body { -webkit-animation: bugfix infinite 1s; }

@-webkit-keyframes bugfix { 
  from { padding: 0; } 
  to { padding: 0; } 
}
```

you can check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/ds2yY/1/

Comment: you aren't even applying the fix i provided there, plus the commented out selector, you are using. this solution fixed his problem, no reason to downvote.

Comment: this bug still present in almost similar situation, and this solution not working

Comment: the bug is not present in the question asked so i really do know how much more you want from me. or what you expect. if you have a question, post it to everyone. nit picking an accepted solution to fit your needs is not the purpose of SO

Comment: Thanks! I used this in my artiyle [Advanced Checkbox Hack](http://timpietrusky.com/advanced-checkbox-hack) to fix the WebKit bug on Android in combination with the [default checkbox hack](http://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/).

Comment: @albert The bug is still present in Webkit. Your bugfixes does the trick, though (thanks!). However, is there a performance issue with constantly animating on the body?

Answer (score 13):

### Easy Fix without Animations

Handled a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219286/why-does-the-general-sibling-combinator-allow-toggling-pseudo-elements-content), where [this idea of changed pseudo-classes solved it](http://jsfiddle.net/ds2yY/24/) (note: `nth-child(n)` will always match):

```
div:hover + a:nth-child(n) + div
```

Comment: amazing. what an obscure bug, and a simple (if obtuse) fix

Answer (score 12):

Alternatively, the fix can be applied only to the elements that are having the update issue rather than to the body element:

http://jsfiddle.net/ds2yY/12/

```
.force-repaint { -webkit-animation: bugfix infinite 1s; }

@-webkit-keyframes bugfix {
    from { fill: 0; }
    to { fill: 0; }
}
```