# CSS Not working On Chrome

Tags: css, html, google-chrome

I am trying to make a cool looking checkbox.I got a checkbox followed by a hidden input then a label.I am trying to change the font weight of the label when the checkbox is checked.

```html
    <html>
    <head>
 <style type="text/css">
   input[type="checkbox"]:checked + input[type="hidden"] + label{
    font-weight:bold;
   }
 </style>
    </head>

    <body>
 <div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="1"/>
  <input type="hidden"/>
  <label for="1">My Label</label>
 <div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

But I can't make it work on Chrome.But if I try this on jsfiddle with chrome it works!!!!!

### [Here is the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9zh477rk/)

Any ideas?

Comment: Overwriting rules maybe?

Comment: It seems your problem is not reproducible. Something else on your page is having an effect on this `<label>`

Comment: why can't you try like this? `input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label{font-weight:bold;}`

Comment: For me it is reproducible on Chrome. Maybe it is and issue for specific versino. I will investigate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome/webkit not rendering css display change on input:checked + element + element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14201694/chrome-webkit-not-rendering-css-display-change-on-inputchecked-element-elem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed your css to the below and it works fine

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + input + label{
                font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: @Emre no probs! But I can't figure out why it wouldn't work when applying the hidden attr.

Comment: Actually css is not wrong, there is a bug with multiple adjacent-sibling selector in some Chrome versions.

Comment: @CemOzer that's what I thought as well but can't understand how it is working on jsfiddle.Most likely it applies some rules that makes it work.

Comment: I have this issue in jsfiddle too, using Chromium 36.0 on Ubuntu 12.04. In FF it's totally fine.

Answer (score 0):

you set minor change  than it's work.

```
<style type="text/css">
        input[type="checkbox"]:checked + input[type="hidden"] ~ label{
            font-weight:bold;
        }
</style>
```