# Accordion Not Working on Chrome Mobile

Tags: css, accordion, mobile-browser, mobile-chrome

I have an purely css accordion that works on chrome desktop and safari mobile, but not the chrome mobile browser. The css and a jsfiddle link are below. What am I missing?

https://jsfiddle.net/BeverlyLeu/0cgf3ejt/1/

```
.transition, .p-accordion, .ul-accordion .li-accordion i:before, .ul-

accordion .li-accordion i:after {
}
.flipIn, .h1-accordion, .ul-accordion .li-accordion {
}
.no-select, .h2-accordion {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.h1-accordion, .h2-accordion {
    color: #468847;
}
.h1-accordion {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 42px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: 100;
}
.h2-accordion {
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 34px;
    font-weight: 300;
  /*  letter-spacing: 1px;*/
    display: block;
    background-color: #fefffa;
    margin: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.p-accordion{
    color: rgba(48, 69, 92, 0.8);
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 26px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    margin-top: 14px;
    z-index: 2;
}
.ul-accordion {
    list-style: none;
    perspective: 900;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.ul-accordion .li-accordion {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    padding-top: 18px;
    border-top: 1px dotted #dce7eb;
}
.ul-accordion .li-accordion:nth-of-type(1) {
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
.ul-accordion .li-accordion:nth-of-type(2) {
    animation-delay: 0.75s;
}
.ul-accordion .li-accordion:nth-of-type(3) {
    animation-delay: 1s;
}
.ul-accordion .li-accordion:last-of-type {
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
.ul-accordion .li-accordion i {
    position: absolute;
    /*transform: translate(-6px, 0);*/
    margin-top: 16px;
    right: 0;
}
.ul-accordion .li-accordion i:before, .ul-accordion .li-accordion i:after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #51a351;
    width: 3px;
    height: 9px;
}
.ul-accordion .li-accordion i:before {
    transform: translate(-2px, 0) rotate(45deg);
}
.ul-accordion .li-accordion i:after {
    transform: translate(2px, 0) rotate(-45deg);
}
.ul-accordion .li-accordion input[type=checkbox] {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
}
.ul-accordion .li-accordion input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .p-accordion{
    margin-top: 0;
    max-height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(0, 50%);
}
.ul-accordion .li-accordion input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ i:before {
    transform: translate(2px, 0) rotate(45deg);
}
.ul-accordion .li-accordion input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ i:after {
    transform: translate(-2px, 0) rotate(-45deg);
}
@keyframes flipdown {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform-origin: to.p-accordioncenter;
        transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    }
    5% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    80% {
        transform: rotateX(8deg);
    }
    83% {
        transform: rotateX(6deg);
    }
    92% {
        transform: rotateX(-3deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform-origin: to.p-accordioncenter;
        transform: rotateX(0deg);
    }
}
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14201694/chrome-webkit-not-rendering-css-display-change-on-inputchecked-element-elem

Answer (score -1):

Try changing all sibling selectors on `:checked` from general to adjacent. So `:checked +` instead of `:checked ~`.