# ~ selector not working in Android

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="test" onclick="this.querySelector('.rad').checked=true;">
   <input type="radio" class="rad" name="rad" />
   <div>hello</div>
</div>
<div class="test">
   <input type="radio" class="rad" name="rad" />
   <div>hello1</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .test input:checked ~ div {
    color: #3498DB !important;
 }
```

This is working fine in desktop browsers and also with user-agent but when I test it on Android devices it is not working. Tested version in Android 4.0+. Someone please tell me how can I fix this?

Note : used onclick instead of ontouchend to post code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/N787h/1/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15192674/css-sibling-selector-not-working-in-android

Comment: @Mr.Alien As per your suggestion I have tried `+` it is working fine in Android 4+ devices. @Fabrizio The code is working fine with Android 4+ devices. I am not sure about 2 and 3 :)

Comment: @redV Undeleted my answer as I had deleted because I wasn't sure

Comment: @redV, nothing to do with your css but if you can give your radios an id, you can wrap the input and div in a label and then you won't need to use js to check the radio when the wrapper is clicked: http://jsfiddle.net/6y7Jy/

Comment: @Pete It is a valid point. But would like to mention that label for will be executed onclick, by the default radio button will be checked after 300ms delay. So, I prefered ontouchend instead of label :) But definitely its valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, as I cannot test it live, but if you want, `+` adjacent selector does the same thing

```
.test input:checked + div {
    color: #3498DB !important;
}
```

As far as your example goes, I don't see any valid reason of using `~` because you are not selecting ALL the `div` elements followed by `input` tag, it's just one in your case.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/N787h/2/)

---

Also, would like to tell you that it's better if you also specify the attribute value using `attr=val` selector like

```
.test input[type="radio"]:checked + div {
    color: #3498DB !important;
}
```

Comment: Will check it and update in few minutes. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: According to [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked#Browser_compatibility) android does support the :checked pseudo class

Comment: Any comments for the downvote? I would really like to edit my answer if it's invalid

Comment: +1 Well, this proves sometimes asking a duplicate question helps :)

Comment: It is a valid answer. My actual requirement is to select all the siblings but it's ok, I can live with immediate sibling selection.

Comment: @redV Not sure, as someone downvoted, but never mind, I just answered keeping the shared markup in mind :)

Comment: @Mr_Green But this page creates a hope that it is working in actual device. In previous question answer says it is not supported and also sibling seldction might be + or ~ :). And I am sory, I was un ware that it was asked already.

Answer (score -1):

The `:checked` pseudo-class is not supported on android devices.

Have a look here : http://quirksmode.org/css/selectors/mobile.html

you can overcome Webkit's pseudo classes + general/adjacent sibling selectors bugs by faking animation on the body element: Check this previus question : [Webkit bug with `:hover` and multiple adjacent-sibling selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320530/webkit-bug-with-hover-and-multiple-adjacent-sibling-selectors/8320736#8320736)

It's a hack but it's a valid solution.