# two labels for one input field with different styles

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I need to have two labels for one input field with different styles.

For some reason this code doesn't work. It does work perfectly for first label, and only partially for second label.

this code works

```
input.switcher[type=checkbox] + label + label
```

but this doesn't (second label doesn't change color by checking on and off)

```
input.switcher[type=checkbox]:checked + label + label
```

any advice how to solve this issue is appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/dantetemp/tLPkk/

Comment: Why do you "need" two labels for one input? More background please, perhaps there's a better solution.

Comment: It isn't working for me in Chrome 28 - Windows 7

Comment: Actually, firefox 20, windows7, no issues :).

Comment: I believe it's a WebKit bug specific to a few versions of Chrome and possibly Safari - I've seen questions similar to this before ..

Comment: yup, seems so. works in IE, FF, Chrome 30. Doesn't work in Opera 15 and Safari 5.1.7

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320530/webkit-bug-with-hover-and-multiple-adjacent-sibling-selectors) question alludes to a similar issue in WebKit, despite it being kinda old.

Comment: This question is also, I think, relevant (albeit I'm not convinced it's a dupe): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219286/why-does-the-general-sibling-combinator-allow-toggling-pseudo-elements-content (disclaimer: that's one of *my* questions).

Comment: This seem like 'A' bug (494 000 answers) : https://www.google.ca/#sclient=psy-ab&q=google+chrome+adjacent+sibling+combinator+checked+bug

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strangely it seems to work (in Chrome 28 - where I presume you have the problem judging by the  comments) if you change the adjacent sibling combinator to the [general sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators), `~` for the second `<label>` - e.g.

```
input.switcher[type=checkbox]:checked + label ~ label {
    color: green;
    font-size: 70px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tLPkk/1/