# CSS chaining adjacent sibling with :checked not working

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-selectors, pseudo-class

Why isn't [**this**](http://jsbin.com/abeniy/1/edit) working for me in Chrome when I click the 2nd radio button? Paragraph 2 stays highlighted and paragraph 4 doesn't get highlighted. Is this a Chrome bug?
HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="toggler" checked />
<p>Paragraph one</p>
<p>Paragraph two</p>
<input type="radio" name="toggler" />
<p>Paragraph three</p>
<p>Paragraph four</p>
```

CSS:

```
:checked + p + p {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me (`Chrome 30.0.1588.0 Dev`; `Blink 537.36`; `V8 3.20.12.1`)

Comment: I'm using Chrome 28. It works OK in FF 23 but not in Opera 15 either. So it must be a browser bug in Webkit.

Comment: Does not work for me in `Chrome 28.0.1500.95`, works in IE 10 and Firefox stable for me.

Comment: @Abraham Chrome 28 was the first version to use Blink.

Comment: I think you have the same issue as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320530/webkit-bug-with-hover-and-multiple-adjacent-sibling-selectors For example: http://jsbin.com/abeniy/7/edit

Comment: @WesleyMurch Seems like it, thanks! Glad to know it's fixed in the upcoming Chrome versions.

Comment: Just add `:checked ~ p {}` and it works (like magic!): http://jsbin.com/abeniy/7/edit

Comment: @WesleyMurch That's awesome, thanks! Gotta love the mysteries of webkit!

Comment: @Abraham I've voted to close as dupe, but I'll post the comment as an "answer" to satisfy protocol, if you are happy with this as a solution. You can flag your post for closure in the meantime if you wish. Or not.  It's an interesting bug.

Comment: @Cole "Cole9" Johnson: Hmm, if this is really fixed in Chrome 30, then it's excellent news. They should consider backporting the fix to WebKit so Apple can use it too. (Why did they even fork it again?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have the same issue as described here:

[Webkit bug with `:hover` and multiple adjacent-sibling selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8320530/398242)

As a workaround just add `:checked ~ p {}` (intentionally empty) and it works:

http://jsbin.com/abeniy/7/edit

Comment: I don't know why this is downvoted - it's the simplest and best answer.

Comment: Just noticed there are several different selectors that will trigger it to work correctly - the shortest I found was `p ~ p {}`

Comment: I guess it is empty but the color must be inherited

Answer (score 0):

That is strange behaviour. I think it has something to do with the `<p>` being siblings of the input element, and not children. I found a bit of a hack as a work around. You simply surround each `input` and `p` block in a `div`. Then use the `~` selector...

the css:

```
input:checked ~ p + p {
        color: red;
      }
```

the html:

```
<div>
<input type="radio" name="accordion" checked />
<p>Paragraph one</p>
    <p>Paragraph two</p>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="accordion" />
    <p>Paragraph three</p>
<p>Paragraph four</p>
</div>
```

the demo:

http://codepen.io/lukeocom/pen/CABes

**UPDATE:**

I just noticed if you add this css to your original html, then it works too. Im not sure why though as the second selector style is empty...

```
input:checked + p + p {
        color: red;
      }

p:nth-child(2){}
```

Comment: Yeah, your second solution is like Wesley's above. Gotta love the mysteries of Webkit! :)